# Нужна ли запятая после "хорошо"?

Tags: пунктуация

В Москве снова жара. Измученные зноем люди с трудом соображают, все реже улыбаются и все чаще ищут повод собрать чемоданы и уехать куда подальше. Хорошо(,) если только на лето.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предложение сложное, сложноподчиненное. Первая часть — односоставное безличное (хорошо), вторая часть — придаточное условия (в каком случае хорошо? — если /уедут/ только на лето), неполное. Запятая нужна.

Answer (score 0):

[**«Хорошо если»**](https://petr-panda.ru/zapyataya-esli/#Horoso_esli)

> Здесь пунктуация будет зависеть от того, частица это или наречие.
>
> **Запятая НЕ нужна**, если это частица, и ее можно заменить выражением «в лучшем случае» (или вообще выбросить):
>
> *На собрание пришли **хорошо если** треть родителей.*
>
> **Запятая нужна**, если «хорошо» – это наречие. Оно является членом предложения, и его нельзя исключить из фразы без потери смысла:
>
> *Будет **хорошо, если** мы приедем на встречу заранее.*

Соответственно, в данном случае запятая НЕ нужна!

Comment: Вы не запутались? Во фразе из вопроса именно наречие. *[будет] хорошо, если только на лето.*  Нет?