# Помогите с запятой после "хорошо"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Хорошо что у него их было много, хватило на всех.

После слова "хорошо" нужна ли запятая?

Comment: См также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6280/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%be

Answer (score 2):

Подчинительный союз **что** соединяет главное предложение *хорошо* (безличное) с придаточным изъяснительным —  это сложноподчиненное предложение, запятая перед союзом необходима.
[СОЮЗЫ](https://school-assistant.ru/?predmet=russian&theme=souz_kak_chast_rechi)

*Хорошо, что нет Царя.

Хорошо, что нет России.

Хорошо, что Бога нет.*

*Только желтая заря,

Только звезды ледяные,

Только миллионы лет.*
Георгий Иванов (1930)

Хорошо, что всё позади.
Хорошо, что нам немного повезло в конце матча.

Comment: Хорошо, что Вы так хорошо все объяснили :) Ставлю плюс.

Answer (score 1):

**Хорошо, что у него их было много.**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение, *что* – союз. Запятая отделяет главную часть от придаточной.